# How to crop and paste an image into an ellipse in pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a drawn ellipse on an image, I want to crop and place into this ellipse an image thumbnail. Here is how the ellipse is placed in the image:
[image]

What I tried to use is paste but that will just cover the ellipse as shown here:
[image]

Here is my pillow code so far:

```
from PIL import ImageFont, ImageDraw, Image
from IPython.display import Image as jpImg
import textwrap
# Start new Image and draw it
image = Image.new('RGB', (1200, 630), color = 'white')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

# Text content to go into image
txt = "This is the title of this entry This is the title of this entry"
list_sections = ['Some section text will go here', 'Some section text will go here 1', 'Some section text will go here 2','Some section text will go here 3', 'Some section text will go here 4'] 
category_list = ['category 1', 'category 2', 'category 3', 'category 4']

# Failed attempt to draw a right angle triangle to divide the image rectangle
#draw.polygon([(1200,630), (200, 200), (150,50)], fill = 'yellow')
# Ending up faking it with a [line]
#draw.line((0, 0) + image.size, fill=128)
draw.line((10,960,1700, 75), fill='red', width=600)

# portion of image width you want text width to be
# matching fontsize to width
img_fraction = 0.50
fontsize = 1  # starting font size
font = ImageFont.truetype("/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf", fontsize)
while font.getsize(txt)[0] < img_fraction*image.size[0]:
    # iterate until the text size is just larger than the criteria
    fontsize += 1
    font = ImageFont.truetype("/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf", fontsize)
# optionally de-increment to be sure it is less than criteria
fontsize -= 1
font = ImageFont.truetype("/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf", fontsize)

# Font for title text
font_title = ImageFont.truetype("/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf", 50)

# Draw sections from list
top = 100
for section in list_sections:
    draw.text((35, top), section, font=font, fill="red") 
    top = top + 40
    continue
    
# Draw Category from list
top = image.size[1] /2
side = image.size[0]-400
for cat in category_list:
    draw.text((side, top), cat, font=font, fill="white") 
    top = top + 40
    continue
    
# Draw parenthesis to surround category list
font_title_parent_0 = ImageFont.truetype("/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf", 350)
draw.text((side - 100, top-300), '{', font=font_title_parent_0, fill=(255, 255, 255, 128)) 
draw.text((side + 240, top-300), '}', font=font_title_parent_0, fill="white") 

# Draw Ellipse for photo
draw.ellipse((300-20,300-20,30+500,30+500), fill='white',outline="red", width=25)
# Paste an image on the eclipse
# offset = ((bg_w - img_w) // 2, (bg_h - img_h) // 2)
offset = ((300-20) // 2, (30+500) // 2)
avatar = Image.open('data/images/avatar.jpeg', 'r')
#image.paste(avatar, offset)

draw.text((10, 15), textwrap.shorten(txt, width=55, placeholder='..'), font=font_title, fill="red") # put the text on the image
image.save('data/images/final_card.png') # save it
jpImg(filename='data/images/final_card.png')
```

Is it possible to crop the avatar thumbnail and place it within the ellipse? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, one way is to load the avatar and mask it then plop it in, as such:

```
image = Image.new('RGB', (1200, 630), color = 'white')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

# draw the border
avatar_size = (200, 200)
x_offset, y_offset = 300, 300
border_bounding = [x_offset, y_offset, x_offset+avatar_size[0], y_offset+avatar_size[1]]
draw.ellipse(border_bounding, fill="red")

# make it into a mask, but scale it down slightly so we have a border
border_size = 25
mask = Image.new('L', [ x-border_size for x in avatar_size ], 0)
mask_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask) 
mask_draw.ellipse([0,0,*mask.size], fill=255)

# crop the avatar into the smaller circle
avatar = Image.open('jake.jfif').convert('RGB')
output = ImageOps.fit(avatar, mask.size, centering=(0.5, 0.5))
output.putalpha(mask)

# now drop that in the center of where our cicle is
image.paste(output, (x_offset+(border_size//2), y_offset+(border_size//2)), output)

display(image)
```

And you get:

[image: cropped image]